# python Calculate with list items

Tags: python, list

this is my list:

```
['-50.00', '60.00', '-63.00', '50.00', '-57.00']
```

How can I calculate with this items

```
-50.00+60.00-63.00+50.00-57.00
```

Comment: Seems like homework?  Also, what have you tried on your own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
temp = ['-50.00', '60.00', '-63.00', '50.00', '-57.00']
sum(float(t) for t in temp)
```

Comment: You can lose the `[]` brackets: a generator expression works there too, not just a list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you, it could be so easy :-)

Comment: @user1443118 -- Careful making statements about what is faster.  For me, `timeit` reports the list comprehension is about 3% faster than the generator.  (the difference here is more or less negligible, but it's worth knowing)

Comment: strange, I'm getting generators to be about 20% faster with Python 2.7 on OsX.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> float(sum(decimal.Decimal(x) for x in temp))
-60.0
```

Comment: Why cast the result to float?  Why not just leave it as decimal?

Comment: Perhaps the OP isn't familiar with decimal yet; hence float makes more sense. But beyond that, no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to convert strings to floats is to use `map`

```
my_list = ['-50.00', '60.00', '-63.00', '50.00', '-57.00']

new_list = map(float, my_list)
```

Result:

```
>>> new_list
[-50.0, 60.0, -63.0, 50.0, -57.0]
>>> sum(new_list)
-60.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use numpy package:

```
    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> my_list = ['-50.00', '60.00', '-63.00', '50.00', '-57.00']
    >>> np.sum(np.array(my_list).astype(np.float))
    -60.0
```